# How can I reduce speed of motor with motor shield?

Tags: motor, arduino-motor-shield

I'm using Arduino and Adafruit to control 4 motors for a little robot.

I have this code example:

```cpp
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ); // create motor #2, 64KHz pwm
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ); // create motor #2, 64KHz pwm
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR12_1KHZ); // create motor #2, 64KHz pwm
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR12_1KHZ); // create motor #2, 64KHz pwm

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Motor test!");

  motor1.setSpeed(200);     // set the speed to 200/255
  motor2.setSpeed(200);     // set the speed to 200/255
  motor3.setSpeed(200);     // set the speed to 200/255
  motor4.setSpeed(200);     // set the speed to 200/255
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("tick");

  motor1.run(FORWARD);      // turn it on going forward
  motor2.run(FORWARD); 
  motor3.run(FORWARD); 
  motor4.run(FORWARD); 
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tock");
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);
  motor3.run(BACKWARD);
  motor4.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("tack");
  motor1.run(RELEASE);
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  motor4.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);


}
```

I want to reduce speed, because now is very fast. If I change setSpeed, the motor have no more force and don't run or not good. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: if reducing speed from setSpeed does not works for you, Its probably power supply/motorDC problem. Keep in minds that motor DC is not a linear actuator